# stuff in quotes are hidden in the compilation error message for gcc?

Tags: colors, gcc, g++

[image]

this happens with both **g++** and **gcc** as whenever I tried `gcc file_name` and the above happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $GCC_COLORS is probably set up for a light background instead of a dark one.

Check with `-fno-diagnostics-colors` in your Makefile or whatever build system you use.  Bear in mind that build script might be setting that variable.

You could also try running without reverse video and see if it works.

The GCC manual has documentation on the GCC_COLORS environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your terminal color scheme conflicts with GCC's default colors. That is, black on black is not visible. This is explained in the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html):

> The colors are defined by the environment variable `GCC_COLORS`. Its
>   value is a colon-separated list of capabilities and Select Graphic
>   Rendition (SGR) substrings. SGR commands are interpreted by the
>   terminal or terminal emulator. (See the section in the documentation
>   of your text terminal for permitted values and their meanings as
>   character attributes.) These substring values are integers in decimal
>   representation and can be concatenated with semicolons. Common values
>   to concatenate include `1` for bold, `4` for underline, `5` for blink,
>   `7` for inverse, `39` for default foreground color, `30` to `37` for
>   foreground colors, `90` to `97` for 16-color mode foreground colors,
>   `38;5;0` to `38;5;255` for 88-color and 256-color modes foreground
>   colors, `49` for default background color, `40` to `47` for background
>   colors, `100` to `107` for 16-color mode background colors, and
>   `48;5;0` to `48;5;255` for 88-color and 256-color modes background
>   colors.
>
> The default GCC_COLORS is
>   `error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01`
>   where `01;31` is bold red, `01;35` is bold magenta, `01;36` is bold
>   cyan, `01;32` is bold green and `01` is bold. Setting `GCC_COLORS` to
>   the empty string disables colors. Supported capabilities are as
>   follows.

You will be able to modify the environment variable `GCC_COLORS` to change `quote` to a different color, something like `01;34`. The wikipedia page on ANSI escape codes has more information.